# Not able to connect GIT through SSH from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, ssh

I am trying to connect GIT repository from eclipse. If I use GIT protocol then I can able to pull the files. But when I trying to connect through ssh protocol I am getting below issue.

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: ssh://username@localhost:8001/Repo: verify: false
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.ListRemoteOperation.run(ListRemoteOperation.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.SourceBranchPage$8.run(SourceBranchPage.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: ssh://username@localhost:8001/Repo: verify: false
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:200)

Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: verify: false
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:126)

I tried adding http.sslverify=false in Git Configuration, adding .git at the end of the URL. But still the issue is not resolved.
```

Please let me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you do a plain `ssh username@localhost` and be successful. If not, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: If I do plain ssh getting below message
$ ssh admin@localhost:8001
ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost:8001: Name or service not known

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to "localhost", then you don't need ssh.
Use the file or "[local protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#Local-Protocol)"

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote set-url origin /home/username/Repo.git
```